# Understanding Spivak's alternative proof that $|a + b|\leq |a| + |b|$

Tags: calculus

For example, in Chapter 1 - Problem 14c Spivak asks the reader to come up with a different alternative proof that

$$|a + b|\leq  |a| + |b|$$

and this is what I found in the solution manual (with my level of understanding written to the right)

Statement (i):

> Since $-|a| \leq a \leq |a|$

*OK, no problem.*

Statement (ii):

> and $-|b| \leq b \leq |b|$

*again, no problem*

Statement (iii):

> it follows that $-(|a| + |b|) \leq a + b \leq |a| + |b|$

*Ok, he added each of the terms from Statement (i) to (ii) in a way to keep the inequality true, got it.*

Statement (iv):

> Thus $|a + b|<= |a| + |b|$

*What?*

Now I have no trouble understanding the assertion that $|a + b|\leq |a| + |b|$... which isn't hard to comprehend and in fact I've proved myself a couple times (albeit in a different way).

What I can't comprehend is how Spivak can make the jump from (iii) to (iv) without making any other additional statements or clarifications. I can work out some interim steps between Statements (iii) and (iv) to prove the assertion is true, but without those interim steps the "proof" doesn't prove anything, in my opinion. He's not remarking upon the characteristics of the numbers, elucidating on properties, or anything.

So, my question is: Is it just me, or is this "proof" not very clear?

Edit:

To expand on my question and to clarify my confusion (as strange as that sounds) it's important to look at the context of the chapter. The chapter revolves around delineating 12 specific properties of mathematics and to show how they can be used to prove all kinds of statements. The properties are:

P1:

> a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c

P2:

> a + 0 = a

P3:

> a + (-a) = 0

P4:

> a + b = b + a

P5:

> a * (b * c) = (a * b) * c

P6:

> a * 1 = a

P7:

> a * 1/a = 1, a ≠ 0

P8:

> a * b = b * a

P9:

> a * (b + c) = ab + ac

P10: For any number a: (paraphrased)

> a = 0
>
> a is in collection P (positive numbers)
>
> -a is in collection P

P11:

> if a and b are in P, then a + b is in P

P12:

> if a and b are in P, then a * b is in P

So up to this point, I've been able to prove just about everything using just these properties, and to my knowledge we've never specifically made the distinction that for any $u \in \mathbb R$ and $a \ge 0$:

$$|u| \le a \iff -a \le u \le a$$

So in using this property as the critical step of his proof, I feel like he's writing something that the reader, who has been told to condense his mathematical knowledge temporarily into these 12 properties, would not understand.

Comment: It is clear - it perhaps isn't very intuitive. To simplify, all the step is saying is that if you have the following: $-a \leq x \leq a$, then $|x| \leq a$ (assuming $a \geq 0$).

Comment: @bof Ah, yes, thats true. I suppose I was a bit careless, thanks.

Comment: I don't have that book, so I don't know what facts have already been established up to the point you're asking about. To get from $-a\le u\le a$ to $|u|\le a$ we need three facts: $$\text{(1) either }|u|=u\text{ or else  }|u|=-u$$ $$\text{(2) }u\le a\implies u\le a$$ $$\text{(3) }-a\le u\implies -u\le a$$ Have any of these three facts already been mentioned?

Comment: What??  :-). Hit exactly the same road-block. But, with Spivak one clearly has to pay really close attention to the preceding problems. And, he spells it out, without emphasizing it.  :-(  Hence $-b \le a \le b \iff |a| \le b$. Once you see that pattern, that Spivak statement "so" is just substitution, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 6):

It's not really a big jump, or a jump at all: for any $u \in \mathbb R$ and $a \ge 0$:

$$|u| \le a \iff -a \le u \le a$$

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe I'm not explaining my confusion very well. I understand

Comment: @ShaneT: if this is not what you are asking about, then let me know. I can probably answer your question.

Comment: It's not the validity of the proof that I'm concerned with, but the fact that he skips over the extremely important step in showing that if: −a≤u≤a, then: |u|≤a—considering he hasn't explicitly stated that property yet and this _entire_ chapter is concerned with delineating 12 specific properties of numbers by which all mathematics obeys, it's a somewhat important additional property to mention if you're using it as the crux of your proof, right?

Comment: Maybe you're right; I can't judge a particular issue with a book that I had not read before. However, the proof of that property is quite straightforward: just separate the cases $u \le 0$ and $u \ge 0$, and use the definition of $|u|$.

Comment: Definitely. Well I appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Start reading one line earlier:

> (b) Prove that $-b\le a\le b$ if and only if $|a|\le b$.  In particular, it follows that $-|a|\le a\le|a|$.
>
> (c) Use this fact to give a new proof that $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|$.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I wrote the problem on my paper as: "Write an alternate proof that |a + b| ≤ |a| + |b|, and I never looked back at the question. Thanks for me making me feel dumb! (just kidding, but seriously. Thanks)